# Perform numpy exp function in-place

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, multidimensional-array, exp, numpy-ndarray

As in title, I need to perform `numpy.exp` on a very large ndarray, let's say `ar`, and store the result in `ar` itself. Can this operation be performed in-place?

Comment: I'm not sure you can do this without temporarily allocating an array. If you could, I don't see how that would work with fast vectorization in numpy.

Comment: what is wrong with `ar = np.exp(ar)`.  @AndrasDeak, is that what you meant?

Comment: @piRSquared I assume OP's point is that if they have 6 GB RAM and 5 GB in `ar`, they can't allocate `np.exp(ar)` alongside `ar` temporarily. And yes, if you *can* allocate temporarily, it's straightforward to do something like that:)

Comment: @AndrasDeak I see.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the optional `out`argument of `exp`:

```
a = np.array([3.4, 5])
res = np.exp(a, a)
print(res is a)
print(a)
```

Output:

```
True
[  29.96410005  148.4131591 ]
```

> exp(x[, out])
>
> Calculate the exponential of all elements in the input array.
>
> ### Returns
>
> out : ndarray
>      Output array, element-wise exponential of `x`.

Here all elements of `a` will be replaced by the result of `exp`. The return value `res` is the same as `a`. No new array is created

Comment: That's probably the most memory-efficient solution possible. I'd still think that there's internal allocation inside `np.exp`, but it probably doesn't get any better than this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Next time I will take a closer look at the docs!

Comment: I don't think there is an internal allocation when `out` is provided.

Answer (score 5):

[Mike Mueller's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41245825/2956066) answer is good but please note that if your array is of type `int32`, `int`, `int64` etc., it will throw a `TypeError`. Thus, a safe way to do this is to typecast your array to `float64` or `float32` etc., **before** doing `exp` like,

```
In [12]: b
Out[12]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], dtype=int32)

In [13]: np.exp(b, b)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError: ufunc 'exp' output (typecode 'd') could not be coerced to provided 
output parameter (typecode 'i') according to the casting rule ''same_kind''
```

Type Casting & exp:

```
# in-place typecasting
In [14]: b = b.astype(np.float64, copy=False)
In [15]: b
Out[15]: array([ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.], dtype=float64)

# modifies b in-place
In [16]: np.exp(b, b)
Out[16]: array([   2.718,    7.389,   20.086,   54.598,  148.413], dtype=float64)
```