# Element wise exp() of scipy sparse matrix

Tags: scipy, sparse-matrix, exponential

I have a very big **sparse csc_matrix** `x`. I want to do elementwise exp() on it. Basically what I want is to get the same result as I would have got with `numpy.exp(x.toarray())`. But I can't do that(my memory won't allow me to convert the sparse matrix into an array). Is there any way out? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you can't hold the input in dense format, you're not going to be able to hold the output; the output won't be sparse, since e^0=1.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you don't have the memory to hold `x.toarray()`, you don't have the memory to hold the output you're asking for. The output won't be sparse; in fact, unless your input has negative infinities in it, the output probably won't have a single 0.

It'd probably be better to compute exp(x)-1, which is as simple as

```
x.expm1()
```

Comment: Yes, you're right. But, how can I do it only for non zero values then?

Comment: What's that? Sparse matrices contain all the numpy functions that happen to map zero to zero as members? There's a feature I wouldn't have expected!

Comment: Yes, `scipy/sparse/data.py` has a block of code that `# Add the numpy unary ufuncs for which func(0) = 0 to _data_matrix.`.  The key is being able to access the `.data` attribute, and make a new matrix with a `_with_data` method.  I wasn't aware of that either.

Answer (score 4):

To change **non-zero** elements, maybe this would work for you:

```
x = some big sparse matrix
np.exp( x.data, out=x.data ) # ask np.exp() to store results in existing x.data
```

presumably slower:

```
# above seems more efficient (no new memory alloc).
x.data = np.exp( x.data )
```

I've been wrestling with how to get an element-wise log2() of each non-zero array element. I ended up doing smth like:

```
np.log2( x.data, out=x.data )
```

The following two techniques seem like exactly what I was looking for.  My matrix is sparse but it still plenty of non-zero elements.

Credit to [@DSM here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29303887/5590742) for the idea of directly changing x.data, I think that is a superb insight about sparse matrices.

Credit to [@Mike Müller](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41245825/5590742) for the idea of using "out" as itself.  In the same thread,  [@kmario23](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41247603/5590742) points out an important caveat about promoting .data to floats (inputs could be int or smth) so it is compatible with the .exp() or whatever function, I would want to do that if I was writing smth for general use.

**note:** I'm just starting to learn about sparse matrices, so would like to know if this is a bad idea for reason(s) I'm not seeing.  Please do let me know if I'm on thin ice with this.

Normally I wouldn't mess with private attributes, but .data shows up pretty clearly in the [attributes documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html#scipy.sparse.csr_matrix) for the various sparse matrices I've looked at.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do something on nonzeros only: the `data` attribute is writable at least in some representations including `csr` and `csc`. Some representations allow for duplicate entries, so make sure you are acting on a "normalised" form.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was thinking of. Anyhow I'll get my hands dirty!

Answer (score 0):

If you just wan to apply some element-wise function only on the nonzero elements, and ignore all other compressed elements (essentially a masked operation), you could do:

```py
y = x.copy()
y.data = np.exp(y.data)
```

Other element-wise function could work as well.

Do note that this is a really **masked** operation, instead of treating all other entries as 0. Because applying a function to 0 may return a nonzero.