# Element-wise absolute value of a sparse matrix

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

How can I get the element-wise absolute value of a sparse complex matrix? In general, is it possible to map a matrix to another using a user-defined function?

Comment: did you actually try `np.absolute(spmat)`?

Comment: You've asked two questions, one very specific and one very general.  The answer to the second will probably depend on how general the user-defined function is that you have in mind.  Could you give some more examples of what you want to do?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Paul Panzer provides the answer to both. My user-defined functions would have mapped zeroes to zeroes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me the following just works

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import sparse

a = sparse.identity(5).tocsr() * 1j
a[2,4] = 1-1j
b = np.absolute(a)
b.A
# array([[ 1.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
#        [ 0.        ,  1.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
#        [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ,  0.        ,  1.41421356],
#        [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ,  0.        ],
#        [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ]])

# general functions: use the data attribute to access nonzeros

b.data = np.exp(b.data)
b.A
# array([[ 2.71828183,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
#        [ 0.        ,  2.71828183,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
#        [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  2.71828183,  0.        ,  4.11325038],
#        [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  2.71828183,  0.        ],
#        [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  2.71828183]])
```

Comment: Didn't we just discover that `sparse` has a version of all `ufunc` that leave 0 values untouched?  It returns a copy of itself, but with the `ufunc` applied to all of its `.data` values.

Comment: @hpaulj yes, so we did. The `data` fiddling is for functions that don't leave 0 untouched. Or are you saying I should have been more didactic about all the other `ufuncs`? You may have a point there. To be perfectly honest I did a quick check and didn't find the `abs` or `absolute` member and, of course, completely forgot about `__abs__`. If you like you can make a post covering the stuff I've omitted.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42408772/element-wise-exp-of-scipy-sparse-matrix - on the discovery that theres a sparse `expm1` method.

Comment: @hpaulj or are you suggesting it's a duplicate? sorry, I'm a bit slow today.

Answer (score 5):

The sparse matrix objects in scipy implement the method `__abs__()`.  That means you can use Python's *built-in* `abs()` function.  It will dispatch the call to the `__abs__()` method.  For example,

```
In [16]: from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix

In [17]: a = csr_matrix([[1+1j, 0, 0, 0], [0, -2, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [3-4j, 0, -5j, 0]])

In [18]: a.A
Out[18]: 
array([[ 1.+1.j,  0.+0.j,  0.+0.j,  0.+0.j],
       [ 0.+0.j, -2.+0.j,  0.+0.j,  0.+0.j],
       [ 0.+0.j,  0.+0.j,  0.+0.j,  0.+0.j],
       [ 3.-4.j,  0.+0.j,  0.-5.j,  0.+0.j]])

In [19]: b = abs(a)

In [20]: b.A
Out[20]: 
array([[ 1.41421356,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  2.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 5.        ,  0.        ,  5.        ,  0.        ]])
```